# Using Custom Emojis in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, emoji

I want the bot to send a custom emoji that in my server when the user gives the command ']rad'. This is my code.

```
@bot.command(name='rad')
async def rolladice (rolladice):
  await rolladice.send ("<:die1:893805362019467295>")
```

But when I use the command **]rad** it sends me this.
[image]

So I tried changing my code like this:

```
dieemote = '<:die1:893805362019467295>'

@bot.command(name='rad')
async def rolladice (rolladice):
  await rolladice.send (dieemote)
```

But the same thing happens.[image]

Comment: Is the emoji on the server?

Comment: @Dominik that doesn't matter for bots, bots have something like a mini-nitro, what does matter is if the bot shares a server with the emoji, like if the bot is in the server of the emoji

Answer (score 0):

If the emoji is in the server, use this format: `:die1:`
If the emoji is not in the server and is not animated, use this format: `<:die1:id>`
If the emoji is not in the server and is animated, use this format: `<a:die:id>`
Replace `id` with the Emoji ID.

Comment: the format is not the issue, `<:die1:id>`/`<a:die:id>` works no matter if the emoji is in the server or not, and since it isn't working the bot most likely can't *see* the emoji meaning that it doesn't share a server with the emoji

Comment: How can I Find the emoji ID

Comment: Open Discord in your browser. Then, open your emoji picker choose an emoji and right click its preview like [this](https://i.imgur.com/FHTiL98.png). Then open the emoji in a new tab. The number in the URL is the emoji's ID.